# Getting error "ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-datetime

Here is a sample of the df:

```
pId tPS                 tLL                 dZ
129 2019-12-02 15:04:09 2019-12-02 15:06:31 5f723
129 2019-12-02 15:04:15 2019-12-02 15:06:37 5f723
129 2019-12-02 15:05:15 2019-12-02 15:07:37 5f723
129 2019-12-02 15:05:18 2019-12-02 15:07:40 5f723
129 2019-12-02 15:05:24 2019-12-02 15:07:46 5f723
```

The pID is the ID of a person and I am trying to check the entry, exit and duration time for each ID.

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
stats=df.sort_values(by=['pId', 'tPS', 'tLL'])[['pId', 'tPS', 'tLL', 'dZ']]
pid = ''
enter_t = ''
exit_t = ''

enter_exit_times=[]

for ind, row in stats.iterrows():

    if pid =='':
        enter_t = row['tPS']
        print(enter_t)

    if row['pId']!= pid or ((datetime.strftime(row['tLL'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
                         - datetime.strftime(exit_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()>2*60*60):

    duration = (datetime.strptime(exit_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") -
                datetime.strptime(enter_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

    enter_exit_times.append([pid, enter_t, exit_t, duration.total_seconds()])

    pid = row['pId']

    enter_t = row['tPS']

enter_exit_times.append([pid, enter_t, exit_t])
enter_exit_times_df = pd.DataFrame(enter_exit_times)
```

So here

- `pid` is the id
- `enter_t` is the entering time
- `exit_t` is the exit time
- `tPS` is the in time
- `tLL` is the out time.

I am then creating a list for which I am writing a loop below. Initially, I run it through a `for` loop where I iterate through the rows of the data frame. So there are two `if` loop, one with `pid` where an empty value means it needs to take the `row[tPS]` and if not then it has to run through the not loop. Then I am calculating the duration and then appending the values to the entry-exit times.

I am getting this error:

```
2019-12-02 15:04:09
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                           Traceback (most recent callast)
<ipython-input-411-fd8f6f998cc8> in <module>
12     if row['pId']!= pid or ((datetime.strftime(row['tLL'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
13                              - datetime.strftime(exit_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()>2*60*60):
---> 14         duration = (datetime.strptime(exit_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") -
15                     datetime.strptime(enter_t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
16         enter_exit_times.append([pid, enter_t, exit_t, duration.total_seconds()])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
357     if not found:
358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

**ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'**
```

Comment: Try breaking your code down. I honestly feel like you might not even understand the code you've used there yourself. Break it down, then try to identify the problem so that you can post a more detailed question. And next time, post some code, don't make us do all the effort.

Comment: show df content, provide a [mre]

Comment: I suggest printing out the values of `enter_t` and `exit_t` before the `duration = ...` line. Then check that it matches the datetime format passed to `strptime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `exit_t` is not set *anywhere* in the loop. It is an empty string.  You set it before the loop to `exit_t = ''` but then it's never set again. That's why `strptime` throws the error here:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(' ', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

The solution is to simply set it properly to `"tLL"` (if I understand you correctly).

But I would like to go further and say that I think you are making the code much *much* more complicated that how it should be. My understanding is that you just want to compute the time duration between `"tPS"` (the in time) and `"tLL"` (the out time). Since you are already iterating over each row, you just need to assign the values appropriately

```
pid = row['pId']

enter_t_str = row['tPS']  # strings
exit_t_str = row['tLL']   # strings
```

then convert the datetime strings to datetime objects using `strptime`

```
enter_t_dt = datetime.strptime(enter_t_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
exit_t_dt = datetime.strptime(exit_t_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

then calculate the duration

```
duration = exit_t_dt - enter_t_dt
```

then finally append it to your list

```
enter_exit_times.append([pid, enter_t_str, exit_t_str, duration.total_seconds()])
```

There is no need to keep track of the `"pId"`.

Here's the full code:

```py
stats = df.sort_values(by=['pId', 'tPS', 'tLL'])[['pId', 'tPS', 'tLL', 'dZ']]

pid = ''
enter_t = ''
exit_t = ''
enter_exit_times = []

for ind, row in stats.iterrows():
    pid = row['pId']

    enter_t_str = row['tPS']
    exit_t_str = row['tLL']

    enter_t_dt = datetime.strptime(enter_t_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    exit_t_dt = datetime.strptime(exit_t_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    duration = exit_t_dt - enter_t_dt

    enter_exit_times.append([pid, enter_t_str, exit_t_str, duration.total_seconds()])

enter_exit_times_df = pd.DataFrame(enter_exit_times)
print(enter_exit_times_df)
```

And the output DataFrame:

```
     0                    1                    2      3
0  129  2019-12-02 15:04:09  2019-12-02 15:06:31  142.0
1  129  2019-12-02 15:04:15  2019-12-02 15:06:37  142.0
2  129  2019-12-02 15:05:15  2019-12-02 15:07:37  142.0
3  129  2019-12-02 15:05:18  2019-12-02 15:07:40  142.0
4  129  2019-12-02 15:05:24  2019-12-02 15:07:46  142.0
```

If you want to only get the enter/exit times for a particular time period of a day, you could create the `datetime` objects for the start and end times, and do regular comparison:

```
>>> dt_beg = datetime(2019,12,2,8,0,0)   #8AM
>>> dt_beg
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 8, 0)
>>> dt_end = datetime(2019,12,2,10,0,0)  #10AM
>>> dt_end
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 10, 0)
>>> dt = datetime(2019,12,2,9,34,0)      #9:34AM
>>> dt_beg < dt < dt_end
True
>>> dt = datetime(2019,12,2,14,34,0)     #2:34PM
>>> dt_beg < dt < dt_end
False
```

So you could add a filter for what to append to `enter_exit_times`:

```
if (enter_t_dt > start_dt and exit_t_dt < end_dt):
    enter_exit_times.append(...)
```

Comment: This is extremely clear... Thanks a lot. ..but is there a possibility for us to filter it for a particular time every day .. maybe like 08 am to 10 am and see the duration spent by each PID between that time every day?

Comment: @ghost22111 Yes, you can. `datetime` objects can be compared to each other just like regular numbers. You could set a start time and an end time, then check if `enter_t_dt` is after the start time and `exit_t_dt` is before the end time. See my updated answer.